# how to unflatten a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, nested

How can I populate a matrix from a list of numbers.

I know this creates matrix. result = [[0 for x in range(3)]  for y in range(3)].

I would like to know how to populate this matrix with from a list of numbers.

List1= [30, 18, 32, 66, 48, 77, 102, 78, 122]. This list comes from a matrix that I flattened. Now I would like to unflatten it.

output = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

I am trying to iterate to populate the matrix. But I end up with the last number.

List1= [30, 18, 32, 66, 48, 77, 102, 78, 122]

```
d=0
while d < len(List1):
     result= [[List1 [d] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
     d+= 1
result= [[122, 122, 122], [122, 122, 122], [122, 122, 122]]
```

Comment: If you can use numpy you can just do `np.array(List1).reshape((3,3))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use numpy, then basically you need to index into `List1` using the `i` and `j` iterator values; using one as column address and the other as row. Dependent on your desired output, you would use either:

```py
result = [[List1[i*3+j] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Output

```py
[[30, 18, 32], [66, 48, 77], [102, 78, 122]]
```

or

```
result = [[List1[j*3+i] for j in range(3)] for i in range(3)]
```

Output

```py
[[30, 66, 102], [18, 48, 78], [32, 77, 122]]
```

Comment: I do not understand this operation : "[i*3+j]." everything else, I understand. I am learning python. I never saw this time of operation inside an index.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try this: `for i in range(3):  for j in range(3):  print(i*3+j, List1[i*3+j])`, you will see that the value iterate through all the possible indexes of `List1` (`List1` has 9 elements which can be accessed as `List1[0]` through `List1[8]`. That should help explain how it works.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks. I upvoted your answer, but since I am new they did not count it.

Comment: @ Nick thanks again. I learned a lot with your answer. Now, I will look for a good website to practice these types of list generators.

Comment: @simplementehumano no worries; I'm glad it was helpful. If you're looking for good websites to test your python code, you can look at [rextester](https://rextester.com/l/python3_online_compiler) and [ideone](https://ideone.com) amongst others...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!